# How to integrate cb-api(career builder) gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, integration

I am using career builder gem to connect to career builder site through API and want to display the fetched jobs in my rails app. but i am not getting any results. tried to get the response in all possible ways . but none of the search gave the results

gem references:

https://github.com/careerbuilder/ruby-cb-api

https://www.careerbuilder.com/api/userinfo.aspx

```
    ## in Gemfile

    gem 'cb-api', '~> 23.2', '>= 23.2.1'

    # config\initializers\cb-api.rb

    require 'cb'

    Cb.configure do |config|
        config.dev_key      = 'my_dev_key_added_here'
        config.time_out     = 5
        config.use_json     = true
        config.debug_api    = false
        config.host_site    = 'US'
    end

    ## app\controllers\api\v1\resumes_controller.rb
    require 'cb'
    class Api::V1::ResumesController < ApplicationController 

        def index
        
        job_client = Cb::Clients::Job
        response = job_client.search({ location: 'Atlanta' })

        search_params = { location: 'Atlanta', keywords: 'Database Admin' }
        response = Cb.job.search(search_params)

        response = Cb::Client.execute({  
        keywords: 'ruby on rails',
        location: 'New York, NY'

        })

        response = Cb::Client.execute({  
        keywords: 'ruby on rails',
        location: 'New York, NY'

        })

        jobs = response.results

        if jobs
        render json: {status: "SUCCESS", message: "Fetched all the jobs successfully", data: jobs}, status: :ok
        else
        render json: jobs.errors, status: :bad_request
        end
    end

    end
```

Even though i query as per gem doucumentation its giving error i mean these lines :

```
  job_client = Cb.job
  response = job_client.search({ location: 'Atlanta' })
```

Getting the below error.

```
NoMethodError in Api::V1::ResumesController#index
undefined method `search' for Cb::Clients::Job:Class
```

Can some one help me to fix the error

Comment: Even though i query as per gem doucumentation its giving error i mean these lines :
job_client = Cb::Clients::Job ;
        response = job_client.search({ location: 'Atlanta' })

Comment: In `job_client = Cb::Clients::Job` you want to be assigning an **instance** of job client, but you assign a class instead. You want to do `Cb::Clients::Job.new` or `Cb.job.new`. Looks like it's a bug in the code and documentation of the gem. You may want to report it in the repo.

Comment: Oof... this seems to be an issue since 2017 lol